# Ruby on rails on bigrock hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using bigrock hosting

i want to learn ror
i have putty access with ssh
what i have done is

```
rails new appname -d mysql
Using # Set by Administrator # Ruby on Rails support depends on this script # Do NOT modify unless you know what you're doing export GEM_HOME=/home/user/ruby/gems export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH from /home/user/.railsrc
```

i am getting error

```
   run  bundle install
/home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:302: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/user/public_html/apps in PATH, mode 040777
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/user/public_html/apps in PATH, mode 040777
/home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/user/public_html/app in PATH, mode 040777
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
```

bundle install will cause this error
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
/home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:302: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/user/public_html/apps in PATH, mode 040777

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /opt/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.

please help me to run a app in bigrock hosting

Comment: Never use **shared hostings** for experiments and educations. Most of them has a lot of different problems such as you described (i.e. restricted permissions, unexpected updates, outdated libraries, etc). So, just purchase any $5 VPS server for learning. It save a lot of your time.

Comment: @maxd so there is no solution for this?